# Ubuntu 20.04 Server spamassassin/spamd "internal error, python traceback seen in response." No additional info. How to debug and fix?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, python, spamassassin, spamd

On Ubuntu server 20.04, I am running spammassassin/spamd, postfix/dovecot. In my mail logs at `/var/log/mail.log` I am getting a spamd

> internal error, python traceback seen in response

error as shown below:

```
Mar  2 12:28:52 mail spamd[26377]: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:34916 to port 783, fd 5
Mar  2 12:28:52 mail spamd[26377]: spamd: using default config for user123: /var/vmail///spamassassin/user_prefs
Mar  2 12:28:52 mail spamd[26377]: spamd: processing message <01000186a3958131-57b1229e-ca0a-482f-845d-4753d517817c-000000@email.amazonses.com> for user123:2000
Mar  2 12:28:53 mail spamd[26378]: internal error, python traceback seen in response
Mar  2 12:28:53 mail spamd[26378]: spamd: clean message (-96.9/5.0) for user123:2000 in 3.9 seconds, 22020 bytes.
```

No other info about the error is in the logs. What is the meaning of this error, how can I diagnose, debug, and fix it so it no longer appears?

Comment: The only place where this string appears in the SpamAssassin code base is the Pyzor plugin. Try disabling Pyzor with `use_pyzor 0`.

Comment: Thanks @glts, but before I do that, what does that plugin do and how will it affect my system by disabling it? Lastly, how exactly do I disable it?