# "mail spamd[495361]: internal error, python traceback seen in response" on Ubuntu 20.04 when receiving email from gmail. How to debug and fix?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, spamassassin

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi. It is set up as a web/email LEMP server. When I send an email from my gmail account to a an email address on my LEMP server, I get an error from `spamd` stating `internal error, python traceback seen in response` in my server's mail logs. See below...

```
Jul 29 10:14:23 mail opendkim[1686]: 3F2031EA70E: s=20221208 d=gmail.com a=rsa-sha256 SSL
Jul 29 10:14:23 mail opendmarc[1673]: 3F2031EA70E: gmail.com pass
Jul 29 10:14:23 mail spamd[495361]: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:58746 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 29 10:14:23 mail spamd[495361]: spamd: using default config for myemailuser: /var/vmail///spamassassin/user_prefs
Jul 29 10:14:23 mail spamd[495361]: spamd: processing message <0C33089E-D539-4FDD-883C-29BD9790E92B@gmail.com> for myemailuser:2000
Jul 29 10:14:26 mail spamd[1129706]: util: setuid: ruid=2000 euid=2000 rgid=2000 2000 2000 egid=2000 2000 2000
Jul 29 10:14:27 mail spamd[495361]: internal error, python traceback seen in response
Jul 29 10:14:28 mail spamd[495361]: spamd: clean message (-4.2/5.0) for myemailuser:2000 in 5.1 seconds, 32287 bytes.
```

What does `spamd[495361]: internal error, python traceback seen in response` mean? what mechanism is breaking? and how can I debug and fix this error?

Comment: If you wish to draw attention to a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1125159/), please do not repeat it. Instead, improve it and/or add details, logs, configuration and results from attempted diagnostic steps.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even realized I asked this question before. Sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Server spamassassin/spamd "internal error, python traceback seen in response." No additional info. How to debug and fix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1125159/ubuntu-20-04-server-spamassassin-spamd-internal-error-python-traceback-seen-in)

Comment: No it doesn't. A commentor recommends disabling pyzor with use_pyzor 0 command. But gives no details about this command or what it does and how it helps and what exactly this is disableing. I still need help fixing this.